# About functionals, how they are defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

So,easy question, the functionals. That's what i got, a functional is an application starting from $K^n$ and ending in $K^1$ (this explains why the projections are functionals). But im not pretty sure about this definition. It's wrong as i suspect?

Comment: The term *linear functional* is often used to mean a linear mapping from a vector space to its field of scalars.  Perhaps you are asking about this?

Comment: It needn't be $K^n $, it could be any vector space over $K $. It also is usually linear if not otherwise specified.

Comment: @hardmath exactly.

Comment: @lan Oh, thats it, so, for example, also a linear application that takes all the polynomail coefficients  from a vector of the real polynomial spaces and summ them is a functional over R?

Comment: Careful. Projections aren't functionals because they map from a vector space to itself. The fact that the image is one dimensional (and hence "looks like" the field of scalars) doesn't make it a functional.

Comment: @EthanBolker oh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over the field $k$. A *linear functional on $V$* is a map $\varphi:V\to k$ such that for all $u,v,w\in V$ and $\lambda \in k$,
$$
\varphi(u + v) = \varphi(u) + \varphi(v)\,\,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\,\varphi(\lambda w) = \lambda\varphi(w).
$$
In general, a *functional on $V$* is a map $V\to k$ that is not necessarily linear.